# C program to calculate mathematical correlation function/autocorrelation function

Tags: c, arrays, math, correlation, scientific-computing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () 
{
    double g_1, e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, e_5; 
    int k;
   // double e[k];

        e_1 = 3.0;
    e_2 = 9.0;
    e_3 = 27.0;
    e_4 = 81.0;
    e_5 = 243.0;


    g_1 = ((e_1*e_2 + e_2*e_3 + e_3*e_4 + e_4*e_5)/5) - (((e_1)* + (e_2) + (e_3) +(e_4) + (e_5)/5)*((e_1)* + (e_2) + (e_3) +(e_4) + (e_5)/5));
printf("\n\n this is g(1): %f",g_1);


return (0);
}
```

I am trying to write a program that calculates the correlation between values. The mathematical function I have is the autocorrelation function or mathematical correlation function which is

```
g(T) = sum(from t = 1 to m-T) [ (e_t)*(e_(T+t)] - (sum(from t = 1 to m) [e_t/m] )^2
```

where m is the number of values I have.

Above I have tried to do the simplest version by taking 5 numbers and just plugging them into the formula. But eventually I need to be able to read a file containing any number of values from 100 to 5000 and find the correlation between them. I will worry about reading the file to the entries of an array later but first I would like to know is there a logical way of doing this using arrays?

For example I tried to do the following:

```
e[1] = 3.0;
    e[2] = 9.0;
    e[3] = 27.0;
    e[4] = 81.0;
    e[5] = 243.0;

for(k=1;k<=5;k++)
    {   
        g[k]= ((e[k]*e[k+1] + e[k+1]*e[k+2] + e[k+2]*e[k+3] + e[k+3]*e[k+4])/5) - (((e[k] + e[k+1] + e[k+2] + e[k+3] + e[k+4])/5)*((e[k] + e[k+1] + e[k+2] + e[k+3] + e[k+4])/5))
             }
```

But this would only make sense for k=1, because by the time it gets to k = 5, then k+1 will be 6, k+2 will be 7.. and I don't have these values.. But I'm not sure how exactly to program this.. Can anybody help?

Thank you

This is the formula using MathJax

g(\tau) = \sum_{\tau_{0}=1}^{m-\tau} ((\epsilon_{\tau{_0}} * \epsilon_{\tau+\tau_{0}})/m) - (\sum_{\tau_{0}=1}^m \epsilon_{\tau_{0}}/m)^2

an alternative form of the formula is:

g(\tau) = <\epsilon_{\tau_{0}}\epsilon_{\tau_{0}+\tau}>-<\epsilon_{\tau_{0}}>^2

where  means expectation of a.

Comment: Could you edit your post and define your auto-correlation function using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so it is immediately intelligible to the mathematically inclined?

Comment: I've never done this before but I've tried to add it.. doesn't seem to come up as a displayed formula though, anyway the function is this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_(statistical_mechanics) in the 4th line.. 
Mine just differs by having the summations.. I hope you understand what I am trying to say now..

Comment: @haccks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_(statistical_mechanics)

Comment: Its used in statistical mechanics a lot, maybe you've heard it as the two point correlation function?

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui I apologize, apparently MathJax is not enabled on StackOverflow. That's a shame! You can still use **[this site](http://www.hostmath.com/)** to define the MathJaz the represents the auto-correlation function. Then edit your question and add the MathJax representing the auto-correlation function. It won't render on Stack Overflow, but we can copy and paste the expression back to the other site and have it rendered correctly.

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui Could you confirm that this is the expression: g(\tau) = \sum_{\tau_0=1}^{(m-\tau)} ((\epsilon_{\tau_0} * \epsilon_{\tau}+\tau_0)/{m}) - (\sum_{\tau_{0}=1}^m ((\epsilon_{\tau_0})/m)^2

Comment: @awashburn I have edited it and the one thats been edited in is the absolute correct version, I made a mistake in the one that you have pasted since I couldn't see the output. But the edited version contains the right formula now.. I hope its clear now, thank you

Comment: what's t in this formula?

Comment: @zubergu \tau I believe, the input to the function G(\tau) = auto-correlation function

Comment: (e_(T+t)] here, whats t? What's the incrementation variable here?

Comment: hi @zubergu could you paste this: g(\tau) = \sum_{\tau_{0}=1}^{m-\tau} ((\epsilon_{\tau{_0}} * \epsilon_{\tau+\tau_{0}})/m) - (\sum_{\tau_{0}=1}^m \epsilon_{\tau_{0}}/m)^2 
into http://www.hostmath.com/ the formula will be much clearer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `C` code you are looking for would be in this form:

```
  int     tau = 7      
  int     m   = 80;
  double  *e; /* An array filled with m values */
  double  lhs,rhs,answer;
  int     tau0;

  /* Left Summation */
  for(sum=0,tau0=1; tau0 < m-tau; ++tau0)
    sum += e[tau0] * e[tau+tau0]; 
  lhs = sum / m;

  /* Right Summation */
  for(sum=0,tau0=1; tau0 < m; ++tau0)
    sum += e[tau0] / m;
  rhs = sum * sum;

  answer = lhs - rhs;
```

Hopefully this get you closer to your solution.

Comment: Actually just adding one loop to this gives me the right answer that I need. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Glad I could be helpful!

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a how to read a math expression problem.  It seems like in your example, m = 5, so the sums never reference beyond that.

I'm not entirely clear on your equation.  Have tried Mathjax, but the formula is still not clear to me, but...

When translating a math expression to code, think of the summation sign (sigma) as equivalent to a for loop!

when writing the code, write (initially) in the most explicit way possible.  For this problem code TWO for loops, one after the other, NOT nested.  Each for loop does part of the calculation for g(k).

Get this to work for g(1).  Then code a third for loop that wraps or surrounds the two loops you just got working.  This loop will calculate g(1), g(2), etc.  Note. if m is 5 and you only have 5 data points then you can only compute g(1), if m is 6 you can compute g(1) and g(2), etc.

Hope this helps, please post if you more information or questions.

To answer your comment, the following for loop implements a sum or sigma.  Note. This is NOT exactly what your code should do, but it does demo using two for loops.

```
   int g1; x = 0; y = 0;
   int i;

   // compute x = sum(g(i)) + sum(f(i))

   // sum i = 0 to 2 [g(i)]
   for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {x += g[i];}

   // sum i = 0 to 1 [f(i)];
   for (i=0; i < 2; i++) {y += f[i];}

   g1 = x - y^2;
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. But what I'm not getting is HOW to tell it to sum.. for example - forget this, even the simplest summation- if i have to do e(1) + e(2) + e(3).. then do I do.. 

sum = 0
for(k=0;k<3;k++)
   for(n=0;n<3;n++)
    { sum = sum + e(n);}
Although you suggested not to use nested loops.. 

Another thing, because my formula is unclear to you you have said the last thing you've said, because for 5 data points you can calculate 4 correlations..

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui, added code per your comment. For the purposes of our discussion: `x += 1;` is the same as `x = x + 1;`

Comment: If you want you can try pasting this: 

g(\tau) = \sum_{\tau_{0}=1}^{m-\tau} ((\epsilon_{\tau{_0}} * \epsilon_{\tau+\tau_{0}})/m) - (\sum_{\tau_{0}=1}^m \epsilon_{\tau_{0}}/m)^2 into hostmath.com it might be clearer. 

But thank you for your answer I thinkkkkk I may get it.. maybe..

Comment: Okay thanks got it. I'll try it out, it should work! Thank you

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui, please ask if more questions and let me know how it turns out!